# "I'm committed to deliver results" vs. ". . . delivering results"

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'd like to describe myself in a cover letter as someone who's committed to deliver results, but:

Should I use "deliver" or "delivering"?  How do I choose between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start to make it better. We have two constructions:

1. "committed" + full infinitive
2. "committed" + prepositional phrase headed by "to"

We also have two meanings of "committed" (from M-W):

a) [the past participle of "OBLIGATE, BIND"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit)
b) ["having made a pledge or commitment to someone (such as a romantic partner) or something (such as a cause)"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/committed)

(There are certainly other meanings, but these are the main ones at issue here.)

Either construction can have either meaning, but it is common to use construction 1 with meaning a:

> ["a contract committing the company to complete the project on time"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit)

and contruction 2 with meaning b:

> ["strongly committed to the fight for equal rights"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/committed)

In your case, meaning b seems more appropriate, so I would use construction 2:

> I'm committed to delivering results